# Make and receive land line phone calls on my mac?

Tags: iphone, caller-id, modem

I have two phones, an iphone and a land line.

I'm spending several hours a day on the phone.  I know I can use my iphone and my mac working together, but I want to be able to do this with my landline too.

- Headset on a 3.5 mm plug to my mac pro.  (Do I need a splitter for mic and audio out?)
- Call display showing the number in an app, that I can cut and paste into a call log.
- Double click dialing.

I *think* I need a USB or internal card modem for this.

Comment: May i ask if you are confident that your land line is "still" analog? Using SIP would be much easier...

Comment: Let's put it this way:  Our fastest digital service we can get locally is 38,400 baud modem.  We're  40,000 feet from the exchange.  Now that was some years ago.  How do I find out if we are SIP?

Comment: The test is simple - what sort of phone do you plug into the socket, if an old type phone it is analog if digital you will need some special one.

Comment: Standard RJ 4 wire plug.  All my house lines are untwisted pair RGYB color code.  We are rural.  The phone company doesn't want to spend money on us.  In that 40,000 feet there are 9 houses.  Ironically 1 mile west we have 6 pair fiberoptic -- school/library/government SuperNet.  But buying into that is $500/month, plus running the link.

Comment: 38,400 baud. Does that mean ~4.7kB/s? That would be really slow. And i doubt thats enough for SIP to work properly :(.